# IP client torrent in GET request

Tags: c++

I have installed https://github.com/OlafvdSpek/xbt .I use cloudflare and in xbtt does not show the real IP address of the client, shows the local IP of the server. I forcibly added it to nginx `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr break;` to display it in GET requests:

```
1595982801  ::ffff:192.168.4.5  56450   GET /00000002dd0e809ada41d86416fce509/announce?ip=80.212.125.78&info_hash=D%e79%c3%e5f%9c%96%cf~1a8%d7%ef%03%02%07%88%60&peer_id=-UT355W-%88%b2Ma%a0%87%e6%1dN%db%26%2f&port=36217&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=342000&corrupt=0&key=A65806EF&numwant=200&compact=1&no_peer_id=1 HTTP/1.0
```

In XBTT I get IP 192.168.4.5 for all clients. 192.168.4.5 - IP adress server, 80.212.125.78 - real client. I just need to use the real IP, not the local server, this is due to the use of cloudflare. I couldn't take the client's real IP address from the GET request and add it to XBTT, here's how I tried to do it.
1.I add in file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OlafvdSpek/xbt/master/Tracker/tracker.h

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> ip_ = {};
```

2.and change https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OlafvdSpek/xbt/master/Tracker/tracker.cpp

```
memcpy(peer.ipv4.data(), &in.ipv6_[12], 4);
```

changed to

```
memcpy(peer.ipv4.data(), &in.ip_[12], 4);
```

but after after build and restart I get the client's IP address as 0.0.0.0, not the one I need 80.212.125.78

Answer (score 0):

By this statement:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> ip_ = {};
```

It means ip_ is an array of four values from 0..255. The values correspond to the IPv4 address. There is no reason for interchanging the IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. In the source you do that only if the IPv4 address is contained in the IPv6 structure. So the copy you're attempting to do is neither here nor there. Fine, regardless of these semantics, this won't give you the public IP of your network.

If you want a public IP of your network there are ways to get it from any client on your network that is connected to the internet. There are plenty of such solutions.